# Incompatible pointer types Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types initializing `NewCustomCell *` with an expression of type `UITableViewCell *`

```
static NSString *cellID = @"customCell";

NewCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
```

Comment: NewCustomCell is a subclass of UITableViewCell, right?

Comment: Check this out: [7. Implicit downcasting on assignment](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/8-confusing-objective-c-warnings-and.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID]` returns an object with type `UITableViewCell *`. If you know that the cell will always be of type `NewCustomCell *`, then you can tell the compiler to expect that with a cast. Like so:

```
NewCustomCell *cell = (NewCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast it.

```
NewCustomCell *cell = (NewCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
```