# how can I get my custom cell details after getting the index path

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have been doing a lot of searching and have managed to get the index path of the cell that holds the button that was clicked using this code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender
{

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

}
```

now my problem is how to I access the properties of the custom cell like I did in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the cell by calling the tableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: My custom cell class is ResultsCell and if I can UITableViewCell to ResultsCell I get `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'ResultsCell *__strong' with an expression of type 'UITableViewCell *'` And if I just leave it as UITableViewCell I dont have access to my custom cell properties.

Comment: nevermind I had to cast it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220940/incompatible-pointer-types-xcode

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 UITableViewCell* cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Now use that cell to get the properties.